# Android определить местоположение программы

Tags: android, файловая-система, filestream, sd

В чем принципиальное отличие между:

```
getApplicationInfo().dataDir
```

и

```
File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Я понимаю что первая функция вернет расположение каталога где находиться приложение.
Вторая вернет путь если есть sd карта в мобильном телефоне.

Но в чем их принципиальные отличия кроме физического место положения файлов.

К примеру вторая функция какую именно папку вернет? Ту которая выделена для моего приложения на SD диске?

Если у телефона нет сменного SD диска, а только внутренняя память как у Nexus что тогда?

Если мое приложение скачивает файлы из интернета, то сохраняя на  SD мне надо создавать отдельный путь для всего этого или же опять, есть выделенное место для моего приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` вернет путь к SD карте, не к папке, предназначенной для хранения файлов на SD карте для вашего приложения.
`getApplicationInfo().dataDir` вернет путь к директории вашего приложения в `/data/data/`

Вы можете всегда проверить сами, какой путь вернет любой метод просто вызвав его. Я рекомендую в следующий раз, прежде чем задавать вопрос, проверить самому.